# How would you go about creating a pointer to a specific memory address in Rust?

Tags: rust

For example, let's say I want to access whatever value is stored at `0x0900`. I found the function `std::ptr::read` in the Rust standard library, but the documentation isn't super clear on how to use it and I'm not sure if it's the right way.

This is what I've tried:

```
use std::ptr;

fn main() {
    let n = ptr::read("0x0900");
    println!("{}", n);
}
```

but it gives me error `E0277`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want to read a value of type `u32` from memory location `0x0900`, you could do it as follows:

```
use std::ptr;

fn main() {
    let p = 0x0900 as *const u32;
    let n = unsafe { ptr::read(p) };

    println!("{}", n);
}
```

Note that you need to decide what type of pointer you want when casting the address to a pointer.

Comment: As a tiny addition, you can also dereference the pointer (`*p`) to read from it or write to it. Note that those count as a move and may drop the value.

Comment: How to do it without declaring `p` in one line?